# app crashes after adding IBOutlet of NSConstraint

Tags: ios, swift

In my application I have created a IBOutlet of NSConstraint`@IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`, and before I did this my application was working fine, but now it keeps crashing, also in the log I get this error `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080007b4820`. And I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: check if you have multiple connection for this outlet in storyboard? Or the outlet connection is still active.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be connected to your view controller in storyboard.

To check:

Go to the main.storyboard and

[image]

Right click on first tap here button then you see the yellow warning icon, It means it not connected to your constraint. Connect them using the Assistant Editor.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1) Open your storyboard or xib file where that constraint is created.

2) Select controller

3) In the Utilities bar open the Connections Inspector tab

4) Check all your outlets for having connections in the storyboard

In the example below there is a constraint that is allocated in the ViewController class as an outlet, but haven't connected to the real UI object in the storyboard

[image]

So you need to connect it. It should help